# parsing multiple array with c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to get the following json: `first` and `last` I am parsing the json like so:

```
    public class TwitterName
    {
        public string results.name.first { get; set; }
        public string results.name.last { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("first: {0} last: {1}",first,last);
        }
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the website with the random generated info
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://randomuser.me/api/"); 

        //get the response
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


        //read the info
        using(StreamReader st = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = st.ReadToEnd();
            TwitterName tn = js.Deserialize<TwitterName>(objText);

            MessageBox.Show(tn.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am not getting a result back, the following json:

```
{"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"ms","first":"teresa","last":"martinez"},"location":{"street":"4896 avenida de andalucía","city":"santander","state":"aragón","postcode":42314},"email":"teresa.martinez@example.com","login":{"username":"redcat339","password":"dang","salt":"ApZZFECd","md5":"6d928ee42d64390a46e94172fce95453","sha1":"61c911a9b09dc7aaad720db67d3cb39394eaa132","sha256":"e68a5b19b365109e604c6a5b824e257ae04f72757cb8da52f3116add41f33c43"},"dob":"1979-07-06 04:55:11","registered":"2010-12-05 20:10:29","phone":"987-440-069","cell":"620-743-650","id":{"name":"DNI","value":"64190365-N"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/72.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/72.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/72.jpg"},"nat":"ES"}],"info":{"seed":"80aa51e344d0db3a","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.1"}}
```

How do I go about parsing the multi array json, to get the name: first and last

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through your code to see what is happening?

Comment: I would assume you need to create the full object not just a partial one

Comment: `public string results.name.first { get; set; }` that won't compile.

Comment: It's a list of results that contain, first and last. You are not deserializing correctly.

Comment: I know regarding the results.name.first, I put that in so people know what one I am trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the full Json model :

```
public class Name
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int postcode { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string sha1 { get; set; }
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string registered { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Picture picture { get; set; }
    public string nat { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string seed { get; set; }
    public int results { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
   public Info info { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize your Json:

```
        //read the info
        using (StreamReader st = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = st.ReadToEnd();
            TwitterObject tn = js.Deserialize<TwitterObject>(objText);

            foreach (var item in tn.results)
            {
                Response.Write(item.name.first + item.name.last + "<br />");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can generate typed classes from your json response, try http://json2csharp.com/

for example

```
var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var results = jsSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(objText);
```

then you can get first result name as below

```
objText.results[0].Name.name
```

generate classes as below

```
public class Name
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int postcode { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string sha1 { get; set; }
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string registered { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Picture picture { get; set; }
    public string nat { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string seed { get; set; }
    public int results { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public Info info { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`, your type to serialize to must be a 1:1 mapping to the JSON. So something like the following would deserialize:

```
class TwitterName
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

class TwitterUser
{
    public TwitterName name { get; set; }
}

class TwitterUsers
{
    public TwitterUser[] results { get; set; }
}

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var users = jss.Deserialize<TwitterUsers>(jsonString);
```

If this isn't the solution you are looking for, I believe you can have more control over serialization to type using other libraries (i.e. [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)).

You could also dynamically deserialize it to an object graph:

```
dynamic users = jss.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
string firstUserName = users["results"][0]["name"]["first"];
```